# How to figure out which record has been deleted in an effiecient way?

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I am working on an in-house ETL solution, from db1 (Oracle) to db2 (Sybase). We needs to transfer data incrementally (Change Data Capture?) into db2.

I have only read access to tables, so I can't create any table or trigger in Oracle db1.

The challenge I am facing is, how to detect record deletion in Oracle?

The solution which I can think of, is by using additional standalone/embedded db (e.g. derby, h2 etc). This db contains 2 tables, namely old_data, new_data.

old_data contains primary key field from tahle of interest in Oracle.

Every time ETL process runs, new_data table will be populated with primary key field from Oracle table. After that, I will run the following sql command to get the deleted rows:

```
SELECT old_data.id FROM old_data WHERE old_data.id NOT IN (SELECT new_data.id FROM new_data)
```

I think this will be a very expensive operation when the volume of data become very large. Do you have any better idea of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Which edition of Oracle ? If you have [Enterprise Edition](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/license.102/b14199/editions.htm#r63c1-t2), look into [Oracle Streams](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14229/toc.htm).
You can grab the deletes out of the REDO log rather than the database itself

Comment: +1 Streams Change Data Capture is definitely the lightest touch on the source database, but you'll have to make a one-time alteration of the tables to add supplemental logging.

Comment: I am not allowed to modify/add the source table in anyway.The ownership of the source db is belong to another company.

Comment: Oracle Streams has been deprecated as of 12c https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2388741_1.html

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is using the Oracle flashback capability (if you're using version 9i or later):

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2608773

This will allow you to select from a prior database state.

If there may not always be deleted records, you could be more efficient by:

- Storing a row count with each query iteration.
- Comparing that row count to the previous row count.
- If they are different, you know you have a delete and you have to compare the current set with the historical data set from flashback. If not, then don't bother and you've saved a lot of cycles.

A quick note on your solution if flashback isn't an option: I don't think your select query is a big deal - it's all those inserts to populate those side tables that will really take a lot of time. Why not just run that query against the sybase production server before doing your update?

Comment: The direction of communication between the servers is only one way which is from Oracle to Sybase. This is due to some sort of security policy of my client's company.